# webpack version in file name

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

When generating a bundle with webpack I already have plugins to inject the version and date as a comment in the files (WebpackAutoInject).

I am creating bundle in a latest folder, but I also need to be able to create a copy of that same bundle with a specific version like so:

/latest/main_bundle.js

/**1.2.3**/main_bundle.js

Is there a plugin or something to do this out of the box or do I need to create a custom script for this? I need to have multiple copies per bundle.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to create duplicate entries:

- Create the entries as is without version (in folder or file name)
- Create some piece of code going through all entries and creating duplicate entries with the version as a folder or integrated in file name
  ==> you can read out the package.json version for this